# A point in 3D space from an angle

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

I'm currently working on a camera for a game. But I got stuck at the rotation.

When I move my mouse across the x- or y-axis, I want the camera to rotate around my character.

What would be a formula to calculate this vector, if the distance to the character is always the same?

I am doing this in Unity, with C#, if this is of any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function may help: `transform.RotateAround(Vector3 axis, float degree)`
you can read the Unity Script Reference for more info.

-oh and I think you should tag your next questions with "unity3d"
but you get the best Unity3d-help at UnityAnswers-Forum http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I did ask there first, but didn't get any answers. That's why I asked here ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) — they seem to fit more than Euler angles for the purpose of camera movement. The Cartesian vector which you need can be obtained by simple formulas as described there.